# How to show/hide forms & divs with button submit and then timer

Tags: php, jquery, html, hide, show

again as always, thanks for your time. this is driving me crazy.

Note: at no point do i want the page to refresh.

I have a form then a loading bar image then a linked button. the main page starts off with just a form and a submit button

What i would like to do is when the form is submitted the whole `div`(1)& its inside and its contents to disappears, then simultaneously a new `div`(2) in its place, appears with a `loading.gif` image and the `submitted entry`, then after 5 secinds this div disappears and in its place another `div`(3) with a `button` link and text inside appears

`div1`: shows form till button click, 
`div2`: then loading image for 5 secs
`div3`: link and text stays visible

My code as is (nothing hides with it and divs are showin when there not meant to be)

```
 <html>
 <head>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 function countdown() {
 var i = document.getElementById('counter');
 if (parseInt(i.innerHTML)<=0) {
    location.href = '#';
    clearInterval(t);
    exit;
 }
  i.innerHTML = parseInt(i.innerHTML)-1;
 }
 var t = setInterval(function(){ countdown(); },1000);
 </script>
 </head>

 <body>
 <!--1. Show until submit then hide -->
 <div id="div1">
 <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
 Answer: <input type="Text" Name="info" required>
 <input type="Submit" value="Send">
 </form>
 </div>

  <!--2. Show for 5 seconds on submit then hide  -->   
 <div id="div2">
 <?php
 if (count($_POST) > 0 && isset($_POST["info"])){
 // add First and Second Numbers
 $sum = $_POST["info"];
 // their Answer is diplayed 
 echo "&nbsp; Your answer $sum". "<br />";
 echo '<img src="http://i.imgur.com/nh9eh0c.gif" border=0>'. "<br />";
 echo '&nbsp; Submiting answer in <span id="counter"> 5</span>' . "<br />";
 // after 5 secounds this hides and is replace with a button link and the text "thank you"
 } ?>
 </div>

 <!--3. Show after 5 seconds above then nothing  -->  
 <div id="div3">
 <?php  
 echo 'Back home'. "<br />";
 echo '<a href="https://www.google.co.nz/"><img src="http://www.skeletonsthemovie.com/images/home-button-large.png" border=0></a>';
 ?>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Hope this isn't to confusing it was quite hard to word properly.. any help would be amazing !

Comment: Try setTimeout or Jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need something like this

```
         <script>
         $(document).ready(function(){

         $('#submit').click(function(event){

            event.preventDefault();
            $('#div1').css('display','none');
            $('#div2').css('display','block');
            setTimeout(function(){$('#div2').css('display','none');$('#div3').toggle()},5000);
            $.ajax({

                //submit form using ajax
            })
         }) 


         })
         </script>
```

Comment: Hey Testing your script quickly, it does seem to work as it should http://goo.gl/lN2WN

Comment: @user1871802 hey now try this .. http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/7rn-534  I have tested it on my local system and its working fine

Comment: You don't have to submit the form twice do you? because it makes me do it on the demo?

Comment: please try to run this on your local system .. I knw thats problem on fiddle but I dont know why its happening there ....

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery on this.
Just put `setTimeout("$('#div).dialog('close')", 5000);` when you want to close a div after 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

In jquery you can try like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#div2").hide();
    $("#div3").hide();

    $("#submit-button").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        if(event.target == this){
            if($("#info").val() == ''){
                alert("Please enter information.");
                return false;
            }

            $("#div1").hide().;
            $("#div2").show().;
            $("#answer").html($("#info").val());

            $("#div2").delay(5000).fadeOut();
            $("#div3").delay(5000).fadeIn();

            $("#back").click(function(){
                 $("#div3").delay(5000).fadeOut();
                 $("#div2").hide();
                 $("#div1").show();
            });
        }
    });


});
```